# MYSQL - Joining three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables arranged as follows

```
Person               Activity               Person_Activity
-------------------  --------------------   -----------------------------
ID | Name | Dept     ID | Activity | Type   PersonId | ActivityId | Value
-------------------  --------------------   -----------------------------
1    David  2        1   act1        1      2         1             5
2    Jim    1        2   act2        2      2         2             1 
3    Steve  1        3   act3        1      3         3             3
                                            1         1             1
```

I would like to select the value for all Persons in Dept 1 of Activity Type 1. This is easy enough when there is a value in Person_Activity, but when there isnt I still require a listing for that person and activity with value 0. EG.

```
PersonName | ActivityName | Value
Jim          act1           5
Jim          act3           0
Steve        act1           0
Steve        act3           3
```

I have tried selecting from the Person_activity table and using a right join to join person and activity however this does not work for me. Could anyone point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Name, CASE WHEN (pa.Value IS NOT NULL) THEN pa.Value ELSE 0 END
FROM Person p
CROSS JOIN Activity a 
LEFT JOIN Person_Activity pa ON p.ID = pa.PersonId AND a.ID = pa.ActivityId
WHERE p.Dept = 1 and a.Dept = 1
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

And sample fiddle to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03d8b/2

Comment: Thanks, this does as I requested.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a CROSSJOIN? And why filter both by p.Dept and a.Dept when they are the same?

This is simpler

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c6537/3

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Activity, CASE WHEN (pa.Value is null) THEN 0 else pa.Value END
from Person p
left join Activity a on a.Type = p.Dept
left join Person_Activity pa on pa.PersonId = p.Id and pa.ActivityId = a.Id
where p.Dept = 1 and a.Type = 1
order by p.Name, a.Activity
```

If the a.Type field is different from p.Dept, this is the solution:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c6537/5

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Activity, CASE WHEN (pa.Value is null) THEN 0 else pa.Value END
from Person p
left join Activity a on a.Type = 1
left join Person_Activity pa on pa.PersonId = p.Id and pa.ActivityId = a.Id
where p.Dept = 1 
order by p.Name, a.Activity
```

Comment: the a.type = p.dept is not so match a common scene

Comment: I thought that the two fields were equal